# How to indentify original color in a white background picture

Tags: color, transparency, photo-editing, rgb

I have a picture of which contains a letter. The letter had a certain opacity when layered onto the image.
I look to find the original rgb and even opacity of the text that was written upon a white background.

Here is an image:[image]

Also if I have the same text but in a different background color would that help?

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain it's possible to directly glean the original color from a baked-in flat file.

But, I think you can make an educated guess...

Duplicate the layer and set the duplicate layer's blend mode to `Multiply`. Then zoom in and watch the pixels, duplicate the multiply layer repeatedly until you see a pixel (probably in the center of a stoke away from an edge) which is **not** getting darker. That is probably close to the original color.

[image]

It's not as easy to tell in this gif.. but the pixel I chose was one in a sea of changing pixels. The area of color change was greater than what the gif may actually show. That particular pixel remained the same color for 2 iterations of the layer duplicating. That's enough for me to assume it's the original color. If I keep duplicating the multiply layer it's going to eventually start getting darker.